# Format string with special chars

Tags: python

Below code throws KeyError. Any ideas please? I tried doubling the braces but still no luck.

```
v = "My Name='{x[1].name}'"
p = "x[1].name"
pv = 'test'
v = v.format(p=pv)
print(v)
```

I also do not want to create another variable and wanted to work formatting on `v` variable.

expected output

```
My Name='test'
```

Comment: trying to see ```My Name='test'```

Comment: I will have to use ```v``` and format on that variable. I don't want to create another variable for this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must use `{x[1].name}` as a format marker, you can create a suitable object to go in the place of `x`.

```
v = "My Name='{x[1].name}'"

class Foo:
    name = 'test'

print(v.format(x=[Foo,Foo]))
```

Output:

```
My Name='test'
```

Here `x` is a list, `x[1]` is the class Foo, and `x[1].name` is the string 'test', as required.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with p=pv but here is how the string .format() would work.

```
pv = 'test'
print("My Name='{}'".format(pv))
# My Name='test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems important for you to use `x[1].name`,  you could try:

```py
class y:
    name = 'test'

v = "My Name='{p}'"
x = [0, y]
v = v.format(p=x[1].name)
print(v)
```

Comment: I can't change ```"My Name='{x[1].name}'"``` so I have work formatting on this variable only. This is coming from different system.

Comment: @dcu You can always do `v = v.replace("x[1].name", "p")`

Comment: @Tomerikoo My option is to use format rather than replace.

Comment: @dcu I meant: `v = v.replace("x[1].name", "p")` and then you can do: `v = v.format(p='test')`

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo. Good suggestion and work around. As mentioned in my post, I am trying to avoid creating additional variable. But if there is no other solution, I will go with this.

Comment: @dcu ok so just do `print(v.replace("x[1].name", "p").format(p="test"))`. I don't quite understand this variable restriction.